# "Download a copy" button in IE only asks to Save or Cancel, but not Open

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, ie

A user on the same computer goes between two different SP 2013 environments. When clicking "Download a copy" on a document item in one environment, Internet Explorer asks "Do you want to open or save [File Name] from [Domain Name]?" Clicking this same button in a different environment prompts Internet Explorer to ask "Do you want to save [File Name] from [Domain Name]?" with no option to just open.

What do I need to change in the second environment to allow the open as well as save option?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in non-working environment IE

`Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > scroll down to Security > you will find an option "Do not save encrypted pages to disk"`.  Take the checkmark out and that should fix this immediately (no need to restart IE or reload the page)

Refer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3094ac49-8d49-4a60-a7cf-fb12c823e500/ie9-download-manager-will-not-display-open-option-only-save-and-cancel-is-displayed-for?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

Comment: Sadly that box was already unchecked. And I've got the same result with read-only users, as well as site admins, across multiple computers.

Comment: This link look promising https://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.com/2012/10/pdf-document-wont-have-open-option-when.html

Comment: I have added .doc and .docx to allowed mimetypes, but no luck. :/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by going to Central Admin -> Manage Web Applications, clicking the web application row, then General Settings from the top ribbon, and setting Browser File Handling from "Strict" to "Permissive".